# Signing and encrypting e-mails

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, mailkit, smime

I am a beginner in encryption and the like and am currently trying to sign and encrypt emails.
Although I am familiar with the concept of private and public keys, I don't seem to understand an important part.

Example: A company wants to sign and encrypt sensitive accounting data and send it to its customers. However, it only knows the e-mail address of its customers.

Question: Is it possible to send an encrypted and signed e-mail using only the e-mail address? Or do I need additional information such as keys/certificates?

Or is only one certificate for the sender sufficient here?

I currently use MailKit and work with CmsSigner and CmsRecipient. Both of them require a certificate. I have been able to send myself messages where CmsSigner and CmsRecipient use the same certificate.
Do I understand correctly that each additional recipient needs a separate certificate for the CmsRecipient? So the company would have to create/collect certificates for each new customer for a deposited e-mail in order to be able to encrypt and decrypt the messages correctly?

Comment: Signing only add a CRC to a message so that users will know if it was modified.  Most emails are automatically encrypted when port 25 is not used (like 465 or 587).

Comment: _"Question: Is it possible to send an encrypted and signed e-mail using only the e-mail address?"_ - Yes and No. You can encrypt them, alright ;) But if you want the customers to be able to DEcrypt them, you'll need to use their specific public key (assuming we are talking asymmetric encryption). That's why Key Servers exist.

Comment: ^^ Also assuming we are talking about End-To-End Encryption, not just transport encryption.